# Burn Micronucleus bootloader to use ATtiny85 via USB (AVRDUDE)

Tags: arduino, avr, attiny, bootloader, avrdude

I am working on an ATtiny85 USB development board, and I need to flash the Micronucleus bootloader on it. I have heard that this bootloader allows the ATtiny85 to be programmed via USB from the computer, without the need of an external programmer.

So I decided to try to burn it, using the Arduino Uno as ISP. I downloaded the bootloader, AVRDUDE, opened the command prompt (I'm using Windows 8.1), navigated to the .hex file folder and wrote this:

```
avrdude -c arduino -b 19200 -P COM6 -p t85 -U flash:w:micronucleus-1.06.hex -U lfuse:w:0xe1:m -U hfuse:w:0xdd:m -U efuse:w:0xfe:m
```

Does that sounds right? That's what the prompt outputs:

```
C:\Users\Mohamed\Desktop\micronucleus-master\firmware\releases>avrdude -c arduin
o -b 19200 -P COM6 -p t85 -U flash:w:micronucleus-1.06.hex -U lfuse:w:0xe1:m -U
hfuse:w:0xdd:m -U efuse:w:0xfe:m

avrdude: please define PAGEL and BS2 signals in the configuration file for part
ATtiny85
avrdude: AVR device initialized and ready to accept instructions

Reading | ################################################## | 100% 0.02s

avrdude: Device signature = 0x1e930b
avrdude: NOTE: FLASH memory has been specified, an erase cycle will be performed

 To disable this feature, specify the -D option.
avrdude: erasing chip
avrdude: please define PAGEL and BS2 signals in the configuration file for part
ATtiny85
avrdude: reading input file "micronucleus-1.06.hex"
avrdude: input file micronucleus-1.06.hex auto detected as Intel Hex
avrdude: writing flash (8162 bytes):

Writing | ################################################## | 100% 3.91s

avrdude: 8162 bytes of flash written
avrdude: verifying flash memory against micronucleus-1.06.hex:
avrdude: load data flash data from input file micronucleus-1.06.hex:
avrdude: input file micronucleus-1.06.hex auto detected as Intel Hex
avrdude: input file micronucleus-1.06.hex contains 8162 bytes
avrdude: reading on-chip flash data:

Reading | ################################################## | 100% 9.37s

avrdude: verifying ...
avrdude: 8162 bytes of flash verified
avrdude: reading input file "0xe1"
avrdude: writing lfuse (1 bytes):

Writing | ################################################## | 100% 0.02s

avrdude: 1 bytes of lfuse written
avrdude: verifying lfuse memory against 0xe1:
avrdude: load data lfuse data from input file 0xe1:
avrdude: input file 0xe1 contains 1 bytes
avrdude: reading on-chip lfuse data:

Reading | ################################################## | 100% 0.03s

avrdude: verifying ...
avrdude: 1 bytes of lfuse verified
avrdude: reading input file "0xdd"
avrdude: writing hfuse (1 bytes):

Writing | ################################################## | 100% 0.03s

avrdude: 1 bytes of hfuse written
avrdude: verifying hfuse memory against 0xdd:
avrdude: load data hfuse data from input file 0xdd:
avrdude: input file 0xdd contains 1 bytes
avrdude: reading on-chip hfuse data:

Reading | ################################################## | 100% 0.02s

avrdude: verifying ...
avrdude: 1 bytes of hfuse verified
avrdude: reading input file "0xfe"
avrdude: writing efuse (1 bytes):

Writing | ################################################## | 100% 0.02s

avrdude: 1 bytes of efuse written
avrdude: verifying efuse memory against 0xfe:
avrdude: load data efuse data from input file 0xfe:
avrdude: input file 0xfe contains 1 bytes
avrdude: reading on-chip efuse data:

Reading | ################################################## | 100% 0.01s

avrdude: verifying ...
avrdude: 1 bytes of efuse verified

avrdude: safemode: Fuses OK

avrdude done.  Thank you.
```

Is it flashed now? Because when I plug it in the USB port I get this error message: "USB device not recognized". Do I have to install some driver, or flash anything else on the ATTiny85?

Comment: Same Problem to me :( Atmega328p usbasp programer works, but attiny85 micronucleus not working :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably found a solution by now, but for others: in order to use an ATTiny85 with micronucleus via USB, you need a [micronucleus driver installed](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/digistump/DigistumpArduino/master/tools/micronucleus-2.0a4-win.zip), then you can use Arduino IDE if you want - simply add the "Additional Board Manager URL" `http://digistump.com/package_digistump_index.json` under Arduino IDE 1.6.5(or greater)'s Preferences and choose "Digistump AVR boards" under the Tools... Board... Board Manager...

Note: you will upload sketches slightly differently with micronucleus. You must insert / reinsert the ATTiny85's USB plug after the sketch has compiled and is ready to upload.

Answer (score 3):

Looks OK to me.

As I read here (https://github.com/micronucleus/micronucleus)

1) after having burned the bootloader you will have to use the upload tool that comes with the micronucleus bootloader to flash your programs (not avrdude)

and

2) you will have to install drivers depending on your OS.

I guess 2) is your problem right now.