# Software flashing attiny167 from RPi with avrdude

Tags: raspberry-pi, flash, attiny, usb-device, avrdude

I am trying to flash a program onto an attiny167
(already bootloaded with the [micronucleus bootloader](https://github.com/micronucleus/micronucleus))
with a Raspberry Pi via avrdude and USB.

## Background

I have 50 Raspberry Pi 3B's connected to an amazon server collecting data.

I have 50 custom attiny167 based USB sensor PCBs which I will connect to the Pis
via USB ([see this previous issue for more detail](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/280993/how-to-write-bootloader-and-drivers-to-attiny167?noredirect=1&lq=1))
It is a struggle to access and connect each device (especially 50 of them),
and I thus need to be able to reflash a program to them via the commandline of an RPi.

I have bootloaded them all from my windows 10 machine and can flash any program via USB.

## RPis

I have flashed programs from the RPi with an Arduino Uno, both with the IDE and avrdude.
 Arduino and avrdude are installed and working (installed both with apt-get).

The RPi can run an already flashed program, with reading and writing
 possible from the USB device.
 When plugged in the device is viewed by the lsusb command for 5 seconds.
 The pre-flashed program then runs and lsusb shows no device:

**`lsusb` immediately after device is plugged into port**

```
 pi@raspberrypi:/usr/bin $ lsusb
 Bus 001 Device 005: ID 046d:c077 Logitech, Inc.
 Bus 001 Device 006: ID 413c:2011 Dell Computer Corp. Multimedia Pro Keyboard
 Bus 001 Device 004: ID 413c:1005 Dell Computer Corp. Multimedia Pro Keyboard Hub
 Bus 001 Device 007: ID 16d0:0753 MCS Digistump DigiSpark
 Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0424:ec00 Standard Microsystems Corp. SMSC9512/9514 Fast Ethernet Adapter
 Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0424:9514 Standard Microsystems Corp.
 Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

**`lsusb` ~5 seconds after device is plugged into port**

```
 pi@raspberrypi:/usr/bin $ lsusb
 Bus 001 Device 005: ID 046d:c077 Logitech, Inc.
 Bus 001 Device 006: ID 413c:2011 Dell Computer Corp. Multimedia Pro Keyboard
 Bus 001 Device 004: ID 413c:1005 Dell Computer Corp. Multimedia Pro Keyboard Hub
 Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0424:ec00 Standard Microsystems Corp. SMSC9512/9514 Fast Ethernet Adapter
 Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0424:9514 Standard Microsystems Corp.
 Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

#### udev rules

I have followed the
[tutorial for udev rules by digistump](http://digistump.com/wiki/digispark/tutorials/linuxtroubleshooting)
and placed the file at /etc/udev/rules.d/49-micronucleus.rules

UDEV of [tinseey](https://www.pjrc.com/teensy/49-teensy.rules) (similar to bootloaded micronucleus for attiny167)

## AVR Device

[this post](http://www.raspberry-pi-geek.com/Archive/2014/03/Adding-analog-input-to-the-Pi-using-the-Digispark/(offset)/2)
hints it may not be possible,
however this issue may have been resolved, as I am using an attiny167 (rather than an 85),
and the Pi does not reboot on the USB being plugged in.

On using dmesg you can see it is unable to enumerate.
`dmesg`

```
[ 9820.701327] usb 1-1.2: new low-speed USB device number 7 using dwc_otg
[ 9820.803813] usb 1-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=16d0, idProduct=0753
[ 9820.803838] usb 1-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
[ 9825.208851] usb 1-1.2: USB disconnect, device number 7
[ 9828.001334] usb 1-1.2: new low-speed USB device number 8 using dwc_otg
[ 9833.081359] usb 1-1.2: device descriptor read/64, error -110
[ 9833.271389] usb 1-1.2: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[ 9833.461352] usb 1-1.2: new low-speed USB device number 9 using dwc_otg
[ 9833.541349] usb 1-1.2: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[ 9833.731352] usb 1-1.2: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[ 9833.921349] usb 1-1.2: new low-speed USB device number 10 using dwc_otg
[ 9834.341388] usb 1-1.2: device not accepting address 10, error -71
[ 9834.421361] usb 1-1.2: new low-speed USB device number 11 using dwc_otg
[ 9834.841371] usb 1-1.2: device not accepting address 11, error -71
[ 9834.841480] usb 1-1-port2: unable to enumerate USB device
```

## avrdude

I'm using the command, with different serial ports

```
usr/bin/avrdude -p attiny167 -c arduino -C /etc/avrdude.conf -b 19200 -P [COM PORT] -U flash:w:[MyHexFile.ino.hex]:i
```

this gives the error

```
avrdude: ser_open(): can't open device "[COM PORT]": No such file or directory

avrdude done.  Thank you.
```

The same method works with the Uno on the Pi, and the AVR device on my windows 10 machines.

I have updated the configuration file `avrdude.conf` to include the attiny167,
as I did with my windows 10 machine.

## Serial port

serial and ttyACMO appears with Uno in /dev, not for the AVR device.

## Arduino IDE

I've attempted to do this through the IDE but get the error:

```
/home/pi/Downloads/arduino-1.8.1/arduino-builder -dump-prefs -logger=machine -hardware /home/pi/Downloads/arduino-1.8.1/hardware -hardware /home/pi/.arduino15/packages -tools /home/pi/Downloads/arduino-1.8.1/tools-builder -tools /home/pi/Downloads/arduino-1.8.1/hardware/tools/avr -tools /home/pi/.arduino15/packages -built-in-libraries /home/pi/Downloads/arduino-1.8.1/libraries -libraries /home/pi/Arduino/libraries -fqbn=digistump:avr:digispark-tiny -ide-version=10801 -build-path /tmp/arduino_build_279218 -warnings=none -prefs=build.warn_data_percentage=75 -prefs=runtime.tools.micronucleus.path=/home/pi/.arduino15/packages/digistump/tools/micronucleus/2.0a4 -prefs=runtime.tools.avr-gcc.path=/home/pi/.arduino15/packages/arduino/tools/avr-gcc/4.8.1-arduino5 -verbose /home/pi/sensicorn/sensicorn/indoorSoftware/Arduino Code/neopixel_simple/neopixel_simple.ino
/home/pi/Downloads/arduino-1.8.1/arduino-builder -compile -logger=machine -hardware /home/pi/Downloads/arduino-1.8.1/hardware -hardware /home/pi/.arduino15/packages -tools /home/pi/Downloads/arduino-1.8.1/tools-builder -tools /home/pi/Downloads/arduino-1.8.1/hardware/tools/avr -tools /home/pi/.arduino15/packages -built-in-libraries /home/pi/Downloads/arduino-1.8.1/libraries -libraries /home/pi/Arduino/libraries -fqbn=digistump:avr:digispark-tiny -ide-version=10801 -build-path /tmp/arduino_build_279218 -warnings=none -prefs=build.warn_data_percentage=75 -prefs=runtime.tools.micronucleus.path=/home/pi/.arduino15/packages/digistump/tools/micronucleus/2.0a4 -prefs=runtime.tools.avr-gcc.path=/home/pi/.arduino15/packages/arduino/tools/avr-gcc/4.8.1-arduino5 -verbose /home/pi/sensicorn/sensicorn/indoorSoftware/Arduino Code/neopixel_simple/neopixel_simple.ino
Using board 'digispark-tiny' from platform in folder: /home/pi/.arduino15/packages/digistump/hardware/avr/1.6.7
Using core 'tiny' from platform in folder: /home/pi/.arduino15/packages/digistump/hardware/avr/1.6.7
Detecting libraries used...
"/home/pi/.arduino15/packages/arduino/tools/avr-gcc/4.8.1-arduino5/bin/avr-g++" -c -g -Os -w -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections  -w -x c++ -E -CC -mmcu=attiny85 -DF_CPU=16500000L -DARDUINO=10801 -DARDUINO_AVR_DIGISPARK -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR  "-I/home/pi/.arduino15/packages/digistump/hardware/avr/1.6.7/cores/tiny" "-I/home/pi/.arduino15/packages/digistump/hardware/avr/1.6.7/variants/digispark" "/tmp/arduino_build_279218/sketch/neopixel_simple.ino.cpp" -o "/dev/null"
Generating function prototypes...
"/home/pi/.arduino15/packages/arduino/tools/avr-gcc/4.8.1-arduino5/bin/avr-g++" -c -g -Os -w -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections  -w -x c++ -E -CC -mmcu=attiny85 -DF_CPU=16500000L -DARDUINO=10801 -DARDUINO_AVR_DIGISPARK -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR  "-I/home/pi/.arduino15/packages/digistump/hardware/avr/1.6.7/cores/tiny" "-I/home/pi/.arduino15/packages/digistump/hardware/avr/1.6.7/variants/digispark" "/tmp/arduino_build_279218/sketch/neopixel_simple.ino.cpp" -o "/tmp/arduino_build_279218/preproc/ctags_target_for_gcc_minus_e.cpp"

fork/exec /home/pi/.arduino15/packages/arduino/tools/avr-gcc/4.8.1-arduino5/bin/avr-g++: no such file or directory
Error compiling for board Digispark (Default - 16.5mhz).
```

when I type `which avr-g++`: /usr/bin/avr-g++, this is just a copy from my windows machine.
I found this [github issue](https://github.com/Robot-Will/Stino/issues/275)
and it seems to be irrelevant for now, just a path issue.

I've had to use a custom json file for the board manager to find micronucleus and Digispark Pro.

When I plug in the AVR device no new serial port is shown in Tools->Port (unlike Arduino UNO, ttyACM0 appears).

I'd much prefer to do flash via avrdude or similar on the commandline, so I have not focused on this.

---

## My question

Is it possible to flash the AVR device with a Raspberry Pi over USB?
If so, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm not going to add this as an answer because its just a thought but its fairly likely the bootloader is exiting and leaving the USB lines to the program code. You'll have to implement the USB stack in your program (which you probably already have) and add a way to tell the device to jump to the booloader from custom software on the pi side and then begin programming before it exits.

Comment: That's a good thought. You're right, I am implementing the USB  in the program code.
I'll give it a go.
Thanks!