# problem with ATtiny167

Tags: attiny

[image: NEW][image: OLD]

I'm using Digispark Pro with my program successfully.
I bought new  ATtiny167 chip for custom PCB board  (for HID USB device). I use the scheme from: https://electrobattery.ru/product/plata-arduino-digispark-pro-attiny167/ 
and this is not working. Result is: “Unknown USB Device (Device Descriptor Request Failed)”.

What I tried:

1. I read fuse from my digispark pro (E:FE H:DD L:DF). I wrote this fuse successful.  I read flash from my Digispark Pro . I wrote this flash successful. Not working.
2. I tried this variant: [How to write a bootloader and drivers for ATtiny167](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/280993/how-to-write-a-bootloader-and-drivers-for-attiny167). same result.
3. i Tried micronucleus 2.04 (https://github.com/micronucleus/micronucleus) with both fuse variants. same result.

Part2:
I solder out chip (old chip) from my working digispark pro, which successful work with USB. And tried  use this chip on my breadboard. Result: “Unknown USB Device (Device Descriptor Request Failed)”

I tried another variant: i took new chip and soldered it in digispark pro. Try 6 combination: 2 variant of fusses and 3 variant of flash (probootloaderr2.zip from http://digistump.com/wiki/digispark/tutorials/proisp; t167_default.hex dвdrom https://github.com/micronucleus/micronucleus/tree/master/firmware/releases and readed flash from my Digispark Pro). Result: “Unknown USB Device (Device Descriptor Request Failed)”

I returned old chip  to digispark pro. everything works good.

WHAT the problem(((
Please help

I only write fuses and flash to chip. May be i have to do anything else?

Please help.

Comment: Custom pcb? You copied the "Digispark" schematic, did you also copy the board layout and impedance matching for the USB data lines? Can you provide your layout/schematic?

Comment: I added schematic. please see

Comment: Avcc and Agnd must always be connected to power and ground, even if you're not using the adc.

Comment: I connected pin 5 to VCC and pin6 to GND. And try again. same result(

Comment: If pins 5 and 6 are connected then you should show them on the schematic. GND symbols should be pointing down (towards the ground). The GND symbol represents metal plates buried in the ground.

Comment: Please don’t draw ground pointing up.

Comment: Doesn't RESET need to be pulled up?

Comment: reset on my working digispark pro not pulled up

Comment: This site is reserved for design problems and problems of design-equivalent detail, while you are trying to guess at the failure of hardware and software not understood.  An approach consistent with this site would be to debug the actual failure - make sure you haven't mixed up D+ and D-, load a simpler custom firmware which operates other aspects of the chip and eventually the USB.  Debug the actual USB bus operations from the PC side, most obviously the enumerated VID/PID but moving on to viewing a log of the actual bus operations.

Answer (score 1):

I hope you did not copy the schematics. The schematics have power supply pins to the ATTiny167 not connected, so obviously it won't work.

Comment: I added my schematic. please see. power supply is connected

Comment: No, half of the power supply pins are disconnected. See pins 5 and 6.

Comment: I connected pin 5 to VCC and pin6 to GND. And try again. same result(

Comment: I only write fuses and flash to chip. May be i have to do anything else?

Comment: Maybe the AVR is already broken as it was half-powered? Have you tried with an AVR that is known to be working?

Comment: I tried new chip. same result(